# Quick way to monitor property value changes of a given class?

Tags: c#, properties

Say, I wrote a class **ClassA**. It works well until one day I wish to monitor the property value changes and react to the changes. What's the quickest way to do so?

One approach I can think of: make **ClassA** inherit INotifyPropertyChanged, and modify property getter/setter to trigger PropertyChanged event, and do something when event fired.

But this might mean tedius code change if **ClassA** has 10s of properties to be monitored.

Is there any more elegent way of wrapping or modifying **ClassA**, so that I can hook up some reaction logic?

Fantasizing: can Attribute do it? Maybe totally nonsense, I write a attribute and I just need to add this attribute to the properties I wish to monitor. It's better than adding/modifying getters/setters.

Comment: Attributes mean little on their own; you would need additional code that (either at compile-time or run-time) looked for the attribute and actually did something about it (i.e. generating a notifying proxy, inserting IL to raise the `PropertyChanged` event etc.) Let me flip the question, though: under what circumstances would monitoring of class properties be a "surprise"? Can you do some up-front design work so that you know ahead of time and can code accordingly?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352537/replace-property-setter-method-at-runtime) thread.

Comment: Side note: some will consider "class with 10s of properties" to be code smell... Maybe refactoring the class will lead to more reasonable number of properties and it would be OK to simply implement notifications manually.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: 10s of properties could be a class representing real world object... like a car, or a person.

Answer (score 1):

Something you may want to look into is using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) In short what this allows you do is put a wrapper around your class methods and properties and react before and or after invoking.

In the wrapper class you will have something like this

```
Invoke(Args[] Args, Aspect Aspect)
{
  //Do something like monitor something here 
  Aspect.Invoke //execution of method or property
 //Do other stuff here... maybe more monitoring
}
```

The beauty about this is separation of concerns. In your ClassA your code can continue to focus on whatever it was focused on before without worrying about the monitoring code. The wrapper is what handles the monitoring.

Reference material:

More info on AOP
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

C# library that you can use to implement AOP in your applications.
Castle Project/Dynamic Proxy
http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy